# xamarin installation and emulator

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have installed xamarin studio in my computer properly. I have checked all installation according to the Xamarin Installer which usually downloads before. I am using window 7.4GB RAM. intel Core I3 processor.

When I select `File` ==> `New` ==> `Solution` and select so `c#`, `F#`, and `VB.net` content is showing.

I am able to select only `C#` => `Android black`, `ice cream sendwitch` .....files only.

How do I create a program for iphone or window phone?

Also if I run code the emulator does not work. The emulator appears but after that no button, label or textbox displays. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Read all of this first. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/. Including abilities of IDE on each platform.

Setup Xamarin.iOS on Windows. 
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/

I believe that Xamarin Studio does not have iOS support on Windows. To do that you have to use MS Visual Studio, and even then you need Mac to build. In essence, you can't develop for iOS unless you have access to Mac.